# log4j 1.2.17 extras - logging to wrong file

Tags: java, date, tomcat, logging

I am running a war within tomcat and noticed some weird issues with logging. For some reason, once a roll-over happens, my logging will write to the old timestamped file (catalina-yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm.log), instead of using the new one like it should (catalina).

I am running log4j 1.2.17 and utilizing the 'extras' jar. Here is part of my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CATALINA
log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.CATALINA.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
log4j.appender.CATALINA.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = [%p] %d{DATE} [%t] %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append=true
```

Here are the files that are generated after a couple of minutes of activity:

```
Sep 28 11:23 catalina
Sep 28 11:23 catalina-2015-09-28-11-22.log
Sep 28 11:24 catalina-2015-09-28-11-23.log
Sep 28 11:25 catalina-2015-09-28-11-24.log
```

If I open up 'catalina-2015-09-28-11-24.log', I see output from 11:25, not 11:24 like I would expect:

```
[INFO] 28 Sep 2015 11:25:02,286
```

Once 11:26 happens, a 'catalina-2015-09-28-11-25.log' will be created for data from 11:26:00 to 11:26:59.

I apologize if this is answered somewhere else, but the only answers I could find suggested using org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender, which is what I am now using and did not resolve the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: log4j says: `Why isn't my rolling file appender properly rolling files or why does logging events get written to the old log file?
    Most commonly this is due to multiple appenders attempting to use the same file path and most likely by having multiple independent instances of log4j read the same configuration file, however having the log file open by another process (an editor, backup utility) can also interfere with rolling. No provided file appender is reliable when multiple instances are writing to the same file path and java.io provides no mechanism to coordinate writing between JVM's.`

Comment: source: [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#rfa). Have you tried using a `DailyRollingFileAppender` ?

Comment: I did try DailyRollingFileAppender and experienced the same issue; that was why i switched to the appender from the extras jar. I only have a single instance of tomcat running and a single war deployed, so I am not sure that multiple instances could be writing to the same file path...

Comment: Maybe you are correct...I downloaded the source code of log4j 1.2.17 and debugged the rollOver() method. When i do so (slowly) the logs are written to appropriately. I am guessing that something else is also trying to write to the same log files and screwing things up.

Comment: don't open log files with notepad or wordpad (notepad++ or glogg is ok) while your app is appending log in it. It often makes the roll-over fail on my comp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the activemq-5.10.0 "all" jar that I was utilizing had a bundled log4j jar that was causing the problem. I changed our project pom dependencies to use the individual active-mq jars and that resolved the issue. (We are utilizing SLF4J, by the way).

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because of the this is how is behaves

> For various technical reasons, rollovers are not clock-driven but
>   depend on the arrival of logging events. For example, on 8th of March
>   2002, assuming the fileNamePattern is set to yyyy-MM-dd (daily
>   rollover), the arrival of the first event after midnight will trigger
>   a rollover. If there are no logging events during, say 23 minutes and
>   47 seconds after midnight, then rollover will actually occur at
>   00:23'47 AM on March 9th and not at 0:00 AM. Thus, depending on the
>   arrival rate of events, rollovers might be triggered with some
>   latency. However, regardless of the delay, the rollover algorithm is
>   known to be correct, in the sense that all logging events generated
>   during a certain period will be output in the correct file delimiting
>   that period.

Comment: I don't think the detailed behavior matches what I am seeing: "regardless of the delay, the rollover algorithm is known to be correct, in the sense that all logging events generated during a certain period will be output in the correct file delimiting that period." My events generated during a certain period are being save to a file delimiting a different period.